# How can I loop over an array in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get data from firebase. But im a bit struggling with that heres how it looks now

```
getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List listOfIds = [];

  QuerySnapshot qn=  await firestore
        .collection('videos')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        setState(() {
         
         
        });
      });
    });

    if (!mounted) return;
    _allResults =qn.docs;
```

What I want is get the hashtasg array field and then add it to  the qn.doc data in _allresults . But how can I do that ?
Heres my firebase so you can see how it looks
[image]

And last step I wanna loop over the howle hashtag array

This is my widget

```
 class Openalldocs extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;
  static const route = '/openalldocs';

  const Openalldocs({Key key, this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenalldocsState createState() => _OpenalldocsState();
}

class _OpenalldocsState extends State<Openalldocs> {
  List _allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];
  Future resultsLoaded;
  bool nosuerfound = false;
  String searchresult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.searchinginput.addListener(_onsearchChanged);
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchinginput.removeListener(_onsearchChanged());

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    widget.searchinginput.text;
    resultsLoaded = getusers();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  _onsearchChanged() {
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = false;
    });
    searchResults();
  }

  searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        var title = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag1
            .toLowerCase();
        var title2 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag2
            .toLowerCase();
        var title3 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag3
            .toLowerCase();
        if (title.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title2.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title3.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List listOfIds = [];
 QuerySnapshot qn=  await firestore
        .collection('videos')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        setState(() {
                       _allResults.add(doc.data()["hashtag1"]);         

         
        });
      });
    });

    if (!mounted) return;

    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    if (nosuerfound == true) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _resultsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // the AMOUNT is how many hashtags you want to show
                for (var i = 0; i < _resultsList.length; i += 1) ...[
                  // the SizedBox will only exist between the elements in the list
                  // as before
                  if (i != 0) SizedBox(height: 6),
                  // create a builder to allow declaring a variable
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      // declare the hashtag variable
                      final hashtag = 'hashtag${i + 1}';

                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          // do something with the hashtag stored in the variable
                          // this will make it relative to the element in the list
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // why is there a Column inside another with only one child?
                            // I would recommend to remove it
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                HighlightedMatchesText(
                                  searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                                  // notice how I am using the hashtag variable here
                                  // instead of a constant? ('hashtag1'), by the way
                                  // the for loop will make the hashtag start at 0
                                  // you can change it by increment in the declaration
                                  // `final hashtag = 'hashtag${i+1}'`, if you want
                                  // the existing behavior
                                  content: _resultsList[index][hashtag],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            // what is this? if it is to add more space between the items
                            // in the list, I recommend removing it from here, and add it
                            // to the first `SizedBox` in the for loop
                            // in case you do that, the Column that this widget belong
                            // would also only now contain one widget, so, there is no
                            // need to have it
                            SizedBox(height: 3),
                          ],
```

Comment: The _allResults is List right?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Firestore methods correctly, the `querySnapshot.docs` is an array of all documents in that collection that you are looping through with `forEach` - You only require further logic on the `doc.data()`.

in this case: push all `"hashtag1"` to the results

```js
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            setState(() {
              _allResults.add(doc.data()["hashtag1"]);         
            });
          });
```

**Update** Suggested code block

```
Future<String> getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List listOfIds = [];
 QuerySnapshot qn=  await firestore
        .collection('videos')
        .get();
for (var doc in qn.docs) {
   setState(() {
                       _allResults.add(doc.data()["hashtag1"]);
        });
}
      });
    });

    if (!mounted) return "Error loading";

    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }
```

Comment: it says then Class 'String' has no instance method 'data'.
Receiver: "#xbxbd"
Tried calling: data()
The relevant error-causing widget was
Builder
lib/homesearchingall/openalldocs.dart:131

Comment: when I removing data() check code so you can see the widget pls

Comment: The resultlist has im setting equal to _allresults list just filtering it later

Comment: try removing the whole `.then` block since you are using await, this allows you to fetch `qn.docs` as your original code.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

This line states that the _resultList is a List of documents, and you want to access all the hashtags from it, because you have the for-loop, which goes until it reaches the length of _resultList, therefore you are getting **all the hashtags**. If you only want to show the **hashtag1**, then change this:

```
content: _resultsList[index].data()[hashtag],
```

to this:

```
content: _resultsList[index].data()["hashtag1"],
```

If you want to have all the documents in this List, use this:

```
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  _allResults = querySnapshot.docs;
}
```

Comment: The second method give no errors but again give all hashtags to the list and not only one the first give this error Class 'String' has no instance method 'data'.
Receiver: "#xbxbd"
Tried calling: data()
The relevant error-causing widget was
Builder
lib/homesearchingall/openalldocs.dart:131

Comment: Then it says type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
The relevant error-causing widget was
Builder
lib/homesearchingall/openalldocs.dart:131

Comment: The resultlist has im setting equal to _allresults list just filtering it later

Comment: giving the same error again first the error Class 'String' has no instance method '..... and then when removing data()     'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' . I understand your idea but he problems is I implemented these hashtags in other region and because of that it will be very hard to reformat all that code this will be my last last like last of last option

Comment: yes then It show me the error again as I said

Comment: Yes please check out I have this textfomfield and giving the value thats tipped in to this widget so I can works with it I only show result thats contains searchinginput. but at start nothing filtered because nothing tipped in just showing all hashtags in that listview . And then for example tipping s only show hashtags that contains the letter s and thats works in another widget also . So again right at the beginning when no user is searching im getting this error and According , I could not test any further

Comment: Ok but now it shows me every hashtag 10 times and also what if I will show hashtag1 and also hashtag 2?

Comment: no in that case I will get all hashtasg but I want only hashtag 1 and hashtag 2 and not hashtag3

Comment: Please check my post I update my code so you can see what happen . I want to avoid something all the time and thats what happen . The hashtags of one video code are hastag1: Mac, hashtag2: apple and hastag3: fuckwindows . So what happen is it shows me the 3 hashtags instead of only too because of that I was trying to getting all hashtasg sepereat . But again this happened . So do you have an solution for that . Do sou think when I create a new array with the hashtags and then lop over it like you said it will not getting this error any more ?

Comment: @dfgdfv yes, you should definitely change it to an array. Then you can pull the data and loop over them, without needing to have a variable renamed or a for loop.

Comment: Should it be a array of all hashtags that ever exist or can I like create a separate array in each video document field because I also have to delete the hashtag away when user delete the video . So what will be the easiest way ? my plan is only creating a array in each videoed with the same name  for this method inside firebase and let all other arrays and functions like they are at the moment

Comment: @dfgdfv use an array called hashtags, there you simply add all the hashtags. Every document in your videos collection should have such an array.

Comment: ok I probably can do this  by my own but with looping would you help me then please ?

Comment: @dfgdfv yes, I will then provide a new answer, you simply need to update your qustion then.

Comment: OK please check my code first again I need to get the hashtags into allresults and then loop over it as you said

Comment: Also  is it then possible to check for equal hashtags and just show equal hashtag 2 times <??

Answer (score 0):

yea check out this. if any error, let me no because i am not on system

```
 List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allResults =[]
    
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
        if (!mounted) return;
    
        setState(() {
          _allResults = qn.docs;
        });
```

Comment: This giving all hashtags to the list